# How to get rid of random groovy error during compile task

Tags: groovy, intershop

At random times I encounter this groovy error during the compile task.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/willem/projects/someproj/projects/someproj/build.gradle' line: 95

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'someproj'.
> Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 14
  Exception Details:
    Location:
      build_wxobn4rxsir22ywxygzua0ka.$getStaticMetaClass()Lgroovy/lang/MetaClass; @6: if_acmpeq
    Reason:
      Expected stackmap frame at this location.
    Bytecode:
      0x0000000: 2ab6 0048 1202 a500 082a b800 4cb0 b200
      0x0000010: 4e4c 2bc7 000f 2ab6 0048 b800 5459 4cb3
      0x0000020: 004e 2bb6 0057 b0                      


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

The only workaround i found so far is to clear the gradle cache and then download all dependency again. Seems like a intershop thing. Found this user also had the same issue:
https://pastebin.com/vzc8RRAa

Does anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I myself get this error occasionally as well. My silver bullet is

```
rm -rf $GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle/caches/2.11/scripts
```

executed from a sourced (i.e. `gradle_environment` script is executed) gradle developer shell. As far as the reason for this goes, I honestly have no clue about this.

Comment: I just saw that you've found a workaround. So my only contribution is that you now know that removing the complete gradle cache is unnecessary.

Comment: I've seen this error after update gradle dependencies in Studio.

Comment: yes I had this after running a gradlew publish through studio, latest studio related probably